# How can I read the comments in the csv files and use them?

Tags: python, csv

```
#StationCode:4845    
#InstrumentKind: CSV  (20191216114518_4845)    
#StartTime:2019/12/16 11:45:28.010    
#RecordLength(sec):103.00    
#SampleRate(Hz): 100    
#AmplitudeUnit:  gal. DCoffset(corr)    
#AmplitudeMAX. a:   15.133 ~   -22.371    
#AmplitudeMAX. b:   70.222 ~   -37.683    
#AmplitudeMAX. c:   13.398 ~   -11.425    
#Intensity:5.0 touC:0.059 PGA:74.4gal PGV:27.7mm/s    
#Time sync.:NTP    
#DataSequence: Time; a; b; c; Pd; Displacement    
#Data: 4F10.3
```

So this is how I have the csv file and these comments are situated at the beginning of the file. Now how can i possibly parse these comments one by one and use them? I came across articles that only helped me strip or ignore these comments while reading the csv file. Correct me if i am mistaken anywhere.

Comment: Properly formatted CSV files don't have comments in them — so you need to defined exactly what format they have in the file you're trying to read (and what parts of it are CSV format data).

Comment: I would suggest using regex and just reading in the text file.See [Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and 
[File Open](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)

Comment: You are mistaken in calling that a .csv file.  .csv stands for "comma separated values" and you do not have a single comma in your file.

Comment: The comments above are just the head part of the csv file i have. i just showed the header here not the entire file. appreciate your correction though, adds to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what you mean by using them one by one. but to get these values into a list. you can use regex.

depending on your needs you can process the comments further to clean them up.

Added a simple comprehension to clean the spaces and add to a dictionary.

```py
s = '''#StationCode:4845    
#InstrumentKind: CSV  (20191216114518_4845)    
#StartTime:2019/12/16 11:45:28.010    
#RecordLength(sec):103.00    
#SampleRate(Hz): 100    
#AmplitudeUnit:  gal. DCoffset(corr)    
#AmplitudeMAX. a:   15.133 ~   -22.371    
#AmplitudeMAX. b:   70.222 ~   -37.683    
#AmplitudeMAX. c:   13.398 ~   -11.425    
#Intensity:5.0 touC:0.059 PGA:74.4gal PGV:27.7mm/s    
#Time sync.:NTP    
#DataSequence: Time; a; b; c; Pd; Displacement    
#Data: 4F10.3 '''

import re

comments = re.findall(r'#(.*)', s)

keys = [x.split(':')[0].strip() for x in comments]
values = [x.split(':')[1].strip() for x in comments]

comments = dict(zip(keys,values))

for k,v in comments.items():
    print(f"key: {k} ---- value: {v}")


# Output: 
#key: StationCode ---- value: 4845
#key: InstrumentKind ---- value: CSV  (20191216114518_4845)
#key: StartTime ---- value: 2019/12/16 11
#key: RecordLength(sec) ---- value: 103.00
#key: SampleRate(Hz) ---- value: 100
#key: AmplitudeUnit ---- value: gal. DCoffset(corr)
#key: AmplitudeMAX. a ---- value: 15.133 ~   -22.371
#key: AmplitudeMAX. b ---- value: 70.222 ~   -37.683
#key: AmplitudeMAX. c ---- value: 13.398 ~   -11.425
#key: Intensity ---- value: 5.0 touC
#key: Time sync. ---- value: NTP
#key: DataSequence ---- value: Time; a; b; c; Pd; Displacement
#key: Data ---- value: 4F10.3
```

Comment: If i can parse these comments singly, i can directly use these data from the comments and insert them to a database. that's what i meant when i said to use them. actually the comments above is just the snippet of the header of the csv file. the detailed data follows in rows and columns. for example, there is a column 'a' in the csv and its lowest and the highest value is already mentioned in the 'amplitudemax, a' comment. so instead of parsing the entire file i could simply use these comments. this was just to clarify my point on 'use'. Thanks anyways :))

Comment: I see. Does the above answer help?

Comment: yes, it does makes sense. do you perhaps have any better or optimal way of parsing? just in case you have. Thankss :))

Comment: It now includes adding the comments to a dictionary, you should be able to move the data around ad needed now.  If this is helpful please mark it as answered &  +1 :)